firebase-analytics-ktx module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1
I can't find these 2 packages in the android file when opening with android studio to change its compiled kotlin version:
jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-21.5.0 and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0
Specifically, my error has content
`e: /home/wido/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/294f8bbb420702a650f9c7c67752a86f/transformed/jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-21.5.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.firebase.firebase_analytics_ktx_granule.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /home/wido/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/95d1ac8af4c1cbdc5c76d29b9b3e5b9d/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
`
My current file
file android/build.gradle
`buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.8'
    }
}`

file android/app/build.gradle
`dependencies {
  
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics"
}`

file android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip`

When I try to upgrade ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0' it continues to crash even more.
